# PHP soap trimming necessary whitespace

Tags: php, xml, soap

So I'm building a soap communicator to transfer data to a client.

In it there is a field that is blank, but can't be communicated as an empty tag, they've requested it to just be a single blank space.

So the data is along the lines of

`$address = array("address1" => " ", "address2" => "123 Fake Street",...);`

When I generate the xml for this I get

`<ns1:Address1/>` instead of `<ns1:Address1> </ns1:Address1>`

The WSDL is Soap 1.2 and utf8 encoded.

I have tried urlencode(), rawurlencode(), utf8_encode() as well as the html &nbsp character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$string = '<![CDATA [ ]]>';
```

Or in the case of your array

```
$address = array("address1" => "<![CDATA [ ]]>", "address2" => "<![CDATA [123 Fake Street]]>",...);
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer isn't completely correct.

The whitespace between CDATA and the bracket results in invalid XML and PHP Soapserver results in "Bad request"

It should be:

```
$string = '<![CDATA[ ]]>';
```